# Why do O(logn) & O(exp(n)) Have Polynomial & Non-Polynomial Running Time Complexities Respectively Despite Their Taylor Series?

Tags: summation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I understand that a function, say $f(x)$, belongs to a class $O(g(x))$ iff:
$$
\exists k > 0 \ \ \exists \ \forall n > n_0: |f(n)| \leq |g(n) \cdot k|
$$

I also know that $log(x)$ is has polynomial running time complexity as can be bounded by some polynomial, say $k \cdot x^m$ where $k$ is a constant, while this doesn't hold true for $exp(x)$. However, what I cannot understand is when we bring our ***old dear friend*** into the play, the Taylor Series:

$$
exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \ \ \ \ \ for \ all \ x
$$

$$
log(1 + x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n} \ \ \ \ \ for \ |x| < 1
$$

Now substituting the Taylor Series of each function respectively, we will obtain for some $m_1$, $m_2$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$:

$$
\exists k_1 > 0 \ \ \exists \ \forall n > n_1: |exp(x) = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{p!}| \leq |x^{m_1} \cdot k|
$$

$$
\exists k_2 > 0 \ \ \exists \ \forall n > n_2: |log(1 + x) = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{p+1} \frac{x^p}{p}| \leq |x^{m_2} \cdot k|
$$

The first of these two statements, is false since $exp(x)$ cannot be bounded by a polynomial. However since we can express $exp(x)$ as the sum of a polynomial, why can't it be bounded by another polynomial?

As for the second statement, that holds true but what I cannot understand **intuitively** is that how can an infinite sum of polynomial terms on the left ever be bounded by a single polynomial term on the right side? 
(Note this logic here directly challenges the reason I purposed in the previous paragraph about bounding but I am mentioning it because I think it is the source of the paradox I cannot solve)

Answer (score 0):

$\log(1+x)=\sum_p^\infty (−1)^{p+1}\frac{x^p}{p},$ only holds for $|x|<1$,
whereas you are interested in $\log(n)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: Fair enough. Although, let us take the Taylor series at $a = x_0$ rather than $a = -1$, we will then have a Taylor series that fits our needs although it's domain might be a bit small, we can always generate a new series if we change "$a$" to whatever suits us. That being said, how can an infinite sum of polynomial terms be bounded by a single term?

Comment: Are you perhaps being thrown off by the fact that the series is telescoping? The $((p+1)$ term x^p that is added to the series is subtracted away in the next term... (up to some fraction at least). Expand the first few terms by hand and pay attention to the telescoping.